# SurfaceView not showing up

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

I have a class which is called when I press a button, the .xml file used as the background is just a black screen.  When I run my application I am getting this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.synlight_development.tattoo_it.Menu$2.onClick(Menu.java:71)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You've implemented it as a runnable. This is probably my lack of knowledge but where do you spin up the thread to call it?

Comment: I have fixed this problem, but have encountered another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278991/android-surfaceview-not-passing-ifholder-getsurface-isvalid-continue

I would love to explain how, but I have no idea...

Answer (score 4):

because of surfaceView default shown on bottom of window.

try this

```
   v.setZOrderOnTop(true);  //it puts surfaceview to top of your window.
```

or also in your SView class set these parameters in constructor etc.

```
   setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

If you want to use GlSurfaceView. In constructor try this,

```
   setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
   getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

thanks to that your surface view becomes transparent.

if you try put your surfaceView to middlelayer of window it's more harder than this

```
   surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

and also you seen black screen because your surfaceview needs another surfaceview to get top of.
I solved this, i create another surfaceView (Maybe you want to use CameraView etc). and drawn
background images, and other surfaceView get top of that, and add another views top of window
like that.

1.Layer -> backgroundDrawnSurfaceView

2.Layer (Middle Layer)->myrealSurfaceView

3.Layer -> Another Views.

Comment: try v.SetZOrderOnTop(true); it solved my problem or in SView constructor-> setZOrderOnTop(true);

Comment: thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You edited your problem

firstly you add SView action listener itself. 
after that in Editor activity onCreate you add onTouch listener to your SView, Editor.
and not found Thread.

try this solution-> delete

```
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and add

```
  sleep(50);
```

in SView, on touch listener.